# Can Azure Data Factory write to FTP

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to write the output of pipeline to an FTP folder. ADF seems to support on-premises file but not FTP folder.

How can I write the output in text format to an FTP folder?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately FTP Servers are not a supported data store for ADF as of right now. Therefore there is no OOTB way to interact with an FTP Server for either reading or writing.

However, you can use a custom activity to make it possible, but it will require some custom development to make this happen. A fellow Cloud Solution Architect within MS put together a blog post that talks about how he did it for one of his customers. Please take a look at the following:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/07/02/creating-ftp-data-movement-activity-for-azure-data-factory-pipeline/

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Upon thinking about it you might be able to achieve what you want in a mildly convoluted way by writing the output to a Azure Blob storage account and then either

1) manually: downloading and pushing the file to the "FTP" site from the Blob storage account or
2) automatically: using Azure CLI to pull the file locally and then push it to the "FTP" site with a batch or shell script as appropriate

Comment: This would create much more moving parts than adding a custom activity, increasing the operational side of things

Answer (score 0):

As a lighter weight approach to custom activities (certainly the better option for heavy work).

You may wish to consider using azure functions to write to ftp (note there is a time out when using a *consumption plan* - not in other plans, so it will depend on how big the files are).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function

You could instruct data factory to write to a intermediary blob storage.
And use blob storage triggers in azure functions to upload them as soon as they appear in blob storage.

Or alternatively, write to blob storage. And then use a timer in logic apps to upload from blob storage to ftp. Logic Apps hide a tremendous amount of power behind there friendly exterior.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Logic app that will pick your file up from Azure storage and send it to an FTP site.  Then call the Logic App using a Data Factory Web Activity.
  Make sure you do some error handling in your Logic app to return 400 if the ftp fails.